# ReactJS: How to test a component function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, meteor, chai

In my meteor application I'm doing some unit testing by testing all methods I'm using. I'm doing the test (mocha/chai) like this:

```
describe('postMessage', () => {
  it('should add message', (done) => {
    // EXECUTE
    const messageId = postMessage.call({ articleId: 123, content: 'Message text' })
    // VERIFY
    const message = Messenger.findOne(messageId) // get data from mongoDB
    expect(message.content).to.equal('Message text') // check for message
    expect(message.articleId).to.be.equal(123) // check for articleId
    done()
  })
})
```

But with this only a part is tested, which is storing the message to DB. But I also have to test if writing a message and submitting it (blur event) will call this method.

This is how my component looks like. I need to know how to do a test for this component. So in this example I need to test if the method `postMessage` is called on blur event of the textarea element and if the state value for `result` gets the ID. How do I do that?

**Component**

```
class Message extends Component {
  addPost (articleId, event) {
    const content = event.target.value
    postMessage.call(
      { content, articleId },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) console.warn(error)
        if (result) this.setState({ result })
      }
    )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Form>
        <TextArea onBlur={this.addPost.bind(this, articleId)} />
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

**Method**

```
const postMessage = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'messenger.insert',
  validate: null,
  run ({ articleId, content }) {
    return Communicator.insert({ content, articleId })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `enzyme+sinon` can help you with that. And I would also keep `blur` behaviour test apart from `addPost` tests, will make it easier to maintain and simpler to read them.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('...', () => {
    it('Calls Message.addPost function when TextArea.onBlur', () => {
        // prepare mock and renders
        Message.addPost = sinon.spy();
        const wrapper = shallow(<Message />);
        const textArea = wrapper.find(TextArea)

        // simulate user action
        textArea.simulate('blur');

        // assert expected outcome
        expect(Message.addPost.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* test this, you can use a [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for `TextArea` to manually trigger a blur event. You should also be able to stub `Message#addPost` to verify that is was indeed called on blur.

That being said, I have to point out that this isn't a particularly valuable test. You've already tested that `addPost` works as expected. By testing that `addPost` is called on blur, you're testing two things:

- React handles events properly
- You're passing a function to `onBlur` and not simply executing a function (an easy mistake for newer javascript developers)

Neither of these are particularly valuable things to test in my opinion.